# TLS 1.2, encrypt_then_mac. No sequence number in packet?

Tags: tls

TLS 1.2, if encrypt_then_mac extension is enabled.

Sequence number is used during MAC calculation.
But it's not used during the 'body' encryption.

Here, seq_num is used only when calling MAC() function:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7366

Does it mean that if client sends some data twice, an encrypted body will be the same each time?
While MAC will be different?

But isn't it insecure for obvious reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the way this is used is secure.  The sequence number increases for each packet and is per direction (one sequence number for client-to-server and an independent one for server-to-client).

However, for the body, there's an explicit IV in each case that is specified in the packet.  For CBC, it must be unique and unpredictable for security reasons, so every packet will end up with a different encryption, even if the data is the same.  For GCM, [RFC 5288](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5288) specifies that there's an implicit 4-byte part of the IV and an explicit 8-byte part of the IV, and that the 8-byte part may be the 64-bit sequence number.  Using the sequence number or a permutation of it is prudent because using a 64-bit random IV would have too high a risk of an accidental collision, breaking the security of the algorithm.  (However, the encrypt-then-MAC extension is not useful with GCM.)

Thus, each packet should have a unique IV if the implementation is correctly configured, which avoids the problem you've mentioned.

Comment: More than merely 'not useful', EtM _does not apply_ to AEAD ciphers including GCM; see 7366 page 4